# Improve query speed with large table and multiple SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have a very large table that looks something like this:

```
event_date (DATE), event_cd (TEXT), bat_id (TEXT)
```

which has a few million rows. `type` is number stored as a string that represents a type of event ('14', '16', etc...). The goal is to calculate a value given a date range and an identifier. I created a function that takes an identifier, a start date (as TEXT) and an end date (as TEXT) and does the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wOBA_period(player TEXT, start_date TEXT, end_date TEXT)
    RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$
WITH guts AS (SELECT * FROM weights WHERE season = substring(start_date FROM 1 FOR 4) :: INT)
SELECT CASE WHEN sum(CASE WHEN ab_fl = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE (round(
    ((SELECT wbb FROM guts) * sum(CASE WHEN event_cd = '14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (SELECT whbp FROM guts) * sum(CASE WHEN event_cd = '16' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (SELECT w1b FROM guts) * sum(CASE WHEN event_cd = '20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (SELECT w2b FROM guts) * sum(CASE WHEN event_cd = '21' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (SELECT w3b FROM guts) * sum(CASE WHEN event_cd = '22' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (SELECT whr FROM guts) * sum(CASE WHEN event_cd = '23' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) :: NUMERIC
        / (sum(CASE WHEN ab_fl = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN event_cd = '14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + sum(CASE WHEN sf_fl = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN event_cd = '16' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) :: NUMERIC,
    3)) END AS woba
FROM events WHERE bat_id = player AND event_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
GROUP BY bat_id;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

Context: it calculates wOBA (weighted on-base average) based on certain events. The formula is the following:

```
wOBA = (wBB*BB + wHBP*HBP + w1B*1B + w2B*2B + w3B*3B) / (AB+BB+SF+HBP)
```

and in the `events` table, the `event_cd` corresponds to one of each of the components in the formula ('20' = 1B, '14' = BB, etc.). Finally, the weights (wXX in the formula) are different each year and stored in a table (`weights`) which I fetched for the given year and temporarily make available as `guts`.

The one problem is that this is very low. It takes ~ 8 seconds to get the result of a call of the `wOBA_period` function. It becomes a bit of a problem when I try to update a different table that needs to make multiple function calls for each of its 5000+ rows.

Is there any way the function could be improved to make it a bit faster?

Thanks

Sample data:

from `events`:

```
event_date  bat_id      event_cd
2015-05-30  linda001    2
2015-05-30  hellj001    20
2015-05-30  incie001    20
2015-05-30  polla001    2
2015-05-30  goldp001    9
2015-05-30  goldp001    23
2015-05-30  trumm001    21
2015-05-30  hilla001    2
2015-05-30  pachj001    2
2015-05-30  ramia001    2
```

So `sum(case when event_cd = '20' then 1 else 0 end) group by bat_id` would return the number of times '20' appeared for a given `bat_id`. This is the number of '1B' in the wOBA formula.

The `weights` table has a line like this for each year:

```
year    wbb     whbp    w1b     w2b     w3b     whr
2016    0.691   0.721   0.878   1.242   1.569   2.015
```

Those are the weights that multiple each component of the formula.

The `wOBA_period` function takes a `bat_id` and 2 dates and should return a single number.

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff added some entries from the `events` table as well as what the `weights` table look like. Thanks!

Comment: I don’t have a copy of your data, of course, but you might try the following: (a) create a `VIEW` with as much as you can process generally; (b) use a function to finish the job. My thinking is that functions are not well optimised, especially if they’re creating a query on the fly, but the view may help.

Comment: @Manngo Ah! Creating a view of the `events` table greatly reduced the query time (0.3-0.8 sec vs ~6-8 sec depending on the range). The view has an additional `year` column so I can narrow it down further that way (date ranges are always the same year). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mast If you don’t mind, I might turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t have a copy of your data, of course, but you might try the following

- create a VIEW with as much as you can process generally
- use a function to finish the job.

My thinking is that functions are not well optimised, especially if they’re creating a query on the fly, but the view may help.